# Is this a correct way of freeing multiple dynamically allocated arrays that are part of a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, free

I am working on C code that reads in binary files, and organises the data contained in these files into a struct before processing. In its most concise form, the main function is structured as follows:
1) read_hgf_file
2) process_contents
3) free_allocated_memory

Because the data consists of recordings at different points in space, the most convenient is to organise the data in a struct with arrays. I have included the definition of this struct in a header file "read_hgf.h", which looks as follows (I am using MSVS 2017):

```
#pragma once
struct HGF {
    int32_t Nrows;
    int32_t Ncols;
    int32_t Np;
    float *data;
    float *xcoords;
    float *ycoords;
    float *zcoords;
};
```

The first three fields help to define the size of the latter four.
In my main function, I call a function that fills these fields with the data from the binary file, which works fine. At the end now, I want to free the dynamically allocated memory associated with this struct. Because it looks messy if I free these arrays one-by-one in the main function, I want to wrap this functionality in a function free_hgf(). Did I understand correctly that I have to free these fields one-by-one, just as they are declared? Would the following be a correct way of doing that, or am I violating any C rules/best practices (particularly related to the combination of the * and -> operators)?

function:

```
#include "read_hgf.h"
void free_hgf(struct HGF **hgf) {
free((*hgf)->zcoords);
free((*hgf)->ycoords);
free((*hgf)->xcoords);
free((*hgf)->data);
*hgf = NULL;
```

}

Called from main as follows:

```
#include "read_hgf.h"
struct HGF hgf;
struct HGF *hgfPtr = &hgf;
free_hgf(&hgfPtr);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's correct, assuming each of the fields was `malloc`ed (or `calloc`ed) before.

Comment: Since you are setting `*hgf = NULL;`  you may want to `free (*hgf)`, assuming its dynamically allocated as well. Other code is fine.

Comment: @Rohan I was thinking something like that, but in the sample code, it's not dynamically allocated. **OP**: _If_ the "real use" uses dynamically allocated `HGF`s, then continue to pass in an `**HGF` and both `free()` and nullify what it points to; if you _don't_ dynamically allocate the `HGF`, then I'd probably only pass in an `*HGF` and free its contents (that way, you could call it with `free_jgf( &hgf );` and not need the (seemingly) temporary/redundant pointer `hgfPtr`.

Comment: Well I have a bad habbit , everytime after every free() I put a Null allocation  i.e.after  free((*hgf)->zcoords); I always have (*hgf)->zcoords=NULL.That saved the day a lot of times.Especially kinky Mondays.

Comment: @TripeHound, in that case there is no point in passing `&hgf` and setting `*hgf=NULL;`.

Comment: @Rohan That's what I said (or at least meant :-) ). _Either_ pass an `**HGF` as currently, free the elements, free the structure and zero the pointer to the structure _**or**_ pass an `*HGF` and just free its elements (no freeing the structure, no setting to `NULL`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the function which fills `HGF` structure is written by you and members of `HGF` structure are allocated with `malloc`, like

```
void read_hgf(struct HGF * hgf)
{
    ...

    hgf->data = malloc(...);
    hgf->xcoords = malloc(...);
    hgf->ycoords = malloc(...);
    hgf->zcoords = malloc(...);

    ...
}
```

Usage of the structure would be

```
struct HGF hgf;

read_hgf(&hgf);

...

free_hgf(&hgf);
```

and freeing part,

```
void free_hgf(struct HGF * hgf) // single pointer is enough to pass a structure
{
    free(hgf->zcoords);
    free(hgf->ycoords);
    free(hgf->xcoords);
    free(hgf->data);

    // clear members
    hgf.data = NULL;
    ...
}
```

Remember if you allocated memory N times (with `malloc`, `realloc`, ...), after you've done using them, you must call `free` N times.

Comment: I think you can clarify the last line, the order of mallocs and frees is important.

Comment: I edited my answer, thx for pointing it out. I would not free them before allocating them tho : )

Comment: @xvnm : Your assumption about the function that fills the HGF structure is correct. This does not imply that my structure itself is dynamically allocated as well, right?
I am a bit confused as to what that means. I thought my struct simply contains the pointers to dynamically allocated arrays, but the structure itself is not dynamically allocated, right? Since its size is known when the program is compiled (I think).
Thank you for the suggestion to set the fields to NULL, I did not think about that.

Comment: The structure itself could be dynamically allocated or not. If you declared it by `struct HGF hgf;` it is not dynamically allocated and you must not call `free`. But, if you did that in following way, `struct HGF * hgf = malloc(sizeof(struct HGF));` it IS dynamically allocated and you must call `free`. I hope it solved your confusion : )